# Iternate array and add strongly typed to list

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following script. When I try to add to list, I get the following message: cannot convert 'System.Collection.Generic.List to Model.Members

```
        List<Members> list = new List<Members>();

        foreach (int i in Ids) // note that Ids is an array of int
        {        
           List<Members> rslt = DataContext.Members(i).ToList();
           list.Add(rslt); // cannot add to list. Get message shown above 
        }
```

Comment: list.ToArray();

Comment: What does `DataContext.Members(i)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataContext.Members(i).ToList() returns a list. You need to use list.AddRange() to add a list to another list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use another method list.AddRange(rslt);
It's for adding sets instead of adding one element